# Change opacity of div ONLY when scrolling - when standing still change back to full opacity

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, opacity

I am looking for a way to change the opacity of a div (.header) to change ONLY when scrolling.

So basically, when you scroll, it becomes almost opaque, but when you stop scrolling, it becomes fully visible again.

I looked for some scripts and kept ending up with these kind of jQuery scripts, but this is only half the solution I'm looking for:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $( ".header #background" ).fadeIn();
    } else {
        console.log('there');
        $( ".header #background" ).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/SEH5M/)

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the scroll event to fade out the element, then set a timeout to restore it (clear the timeout at the beginning of the event handler), then as long as you keep scrolling, the element will stay faded until you stop scrolling for **x** milliseconds (timeout period)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "almost opaque," I assume you really mean "almost transparent."  In that case, you probably don't want to use `fadeOut`, because it will make it *completely* transparent.

You could animate opacity instead.

You can set a timer as others have suggested.

You'll also want to be careful to stop any running animation before starting a new one.

This may accomplish what you need:

```
var timer;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.header').stop().animate({opacity:0.2},10);
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer= setInterval(function() {
    $('.header').stop().animate({opacity:1},'fast');
  },100);
});
```

### Fiddle

Comment: Hello! This works beautifully on your Fiddle but I somehow cannot get it to work. I assume I am making some stupid mistake but I cannot figure it out? This is my current code http://pastebin.com/A9QSw6yB

Comment: In your pastebin, you're linking in jQuery UI, but doesn't look like you're linking in jQuery.  Add this above jQuery UI:  `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

By using a timeout that checks (in this case 200ms) after each scroll event to see if the user has stopped scrolling, you can accomplish this effect.
**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/SEH5M/276/

```
$( ".header #background" ).fadeIn(); //initial fadein
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(!$( ".header #background" ).hasClass('transition')){ //avoid multiple fades
        $( ".header #background" ).stop().addClass('transition').fadeOut();
    }
    var position = $(window).scrollTop();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(position - $(window).scrollTop() == 0){ //check if scroll position has changed

            $( ".header #background" ).stop().removeClass('transition').fadeIn();
        }
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: Hello, this seems to work great! I'm a bit confused with the background div though, does the code also just work for the .header div if it doesn't have a background? Or could you explain me why you added it?

Comment: The background div was part of your original fiddle, so I just kept it there. If you like, remove the `#background` and it'll fade in and out the entire header instead :)